# Losing the local client when calling dark inside of a distributed-spawned function

Tags: dask

I am trying to perform some task operations inside of a function which is sent to a worker through distributed. A simplified version of the code is

```
client = Client(...)
X_ = dask.array.from_array(...)
X = dask.persist(X_)
def func(X, b):
     with distributed.local_client() as c:
           with dask.set_options(get=c.get):
                 return dask.lu_solve(X, b)

client.persist(dask.do(func)(X, b))
```

The problem is that in doing for several `X`, `b` instances, sometimes it works and sometimes I get the Exception `Exception: Client not running.  Status: closed`

any idea on how to address this?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the inputs dask.array `X` and `b` to a dask.delayed function they arrive as numpy arrays.  I recommend just using NumPy functions instead.

Alternatively, maybe you're trying to accomplish something else?

If you want to call a dask.array function on dask.arrays you can do it from your normal python session.  There is no reason to use a `local_client`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

I have several reasons for this design:

1) is that the matrix `X` is very large (10s of GB)
2) the complexity of my actual `func` function is a bit larger than the toy example* and it will be repeated for various `X` instances, so am using dask/distributed to _embarrassingly_ parallelise that part of the problem.

Am I reaching the limits of common dask use-cases?

(* Actually `func` is the `__init__` of a class that performs calculations on the dask arrays and then saves some of them for further calculi.)

Comment: You'll need to think about how to parallelize your function `f` across a distributed array.  Dask won't dive into your custom code for you.  You may want to take a look at map_blocks or dask.delayed.